# Why the app.js isn't being used properly when the react app is deployed on the server?

Tags: reactjs, docker, model-view-controller, server, frontend

When this react app is being deployed on the server which is an ubuntu linux machine server, whenever i run "npm start", **it always only renders index.html**, which means it only returns page title.

When I tried to test on some sample code which was generated by the command of "npx create-react-app test", it also only renders index.html

However, on the local machine, when i run it, it can deploy the whole app successfully, - 
    which means the index.js would be associated with index.html and app.js because of this line of code
`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

But why it wouldn't work in this way on the ubuntu linux machine server?

Also I have generated the "build" folder with using the command of npm run build, but i am not sure does this have anything to do with the problem? and how should I run the command after the "build" folder is created?

Comment: It could be issue of wrong path inside the html, can you see if in network tab, it is able to fetch files like app.<hash>.js and you would be able to see script tag having the relative path for js and css files.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], and describe the actual steps you're running where it doesn't work?